# Save multiple PNG from RGB data frame in R

Tags: r, png, rgb, tidyverse, purrr

I have a data frame which looks like below. I want to save two png files out of this data frame, named based on `sample` column, `1.png` and `2.png` both being 2x3 pixel large using the rgb values on respective columns.

As far as I can tell, I need to prepare a 3d array for each channel and then use `writePNG` function for each array to save as PNG file, but I got stuck after nesting rgb values for each sample.

Any help would be appreciated (help in `tidyverse` and `purrr` way will be appreciated more ;)

Data frame:

```
| sample| pixel| red| green| blue|
|------:|-----:|---:|-----:|----:|
|      1|     1| 255|     0|    0|
|      1|     2| 255|    32|    0|
|      1|     3| 255|    64|    0|
|      1|     4| 255|    96|    0|
|      1|     5| 255|   128|    0|
|      1|     6| 255|   159|    0|
|      2|     1| 255|   191|    0|
|      2|     2| 255|   223|    0|
|      2|     3| 255|   255|    0|
|      2|     4| 255|   255|   42|
|      2|     5| 255|   255|  128|
|      2|     6| 255|   255|  213|
```

Here's the code to generate this data frame:

```
test_df <- data_frame(sample=rep(1:2,each=6), pixel=rep(1:6,2)) %>% 
  bind_cols(as_data_frame(t(col2rgb(heat.colors(12)))))
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to nest rgb values?

Comment: you already answered but I just noticed the comment and still wanted to answer. I used the following command to nest the values:
`test_df %>% group_by(sample) %>% nest()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance:

```
library(purrr)

test_df %>% 
  split(.$sample) %>% 
  setNames(paste0(names(.), ".png")) %>% 
  map(~ array(c(.x$red, .x$green, .x$blue), c(2, 3, 3)) / 255) %>%
  iwalk(png::writePNG)
```

Or in a more "step-by-step" fashion:

```
test_df %>% 
  split(.$sample) %>% 
  setNames(paste0(names(.), ".png")) %>% 
  map(`[`, 3:5) %>% 
  map(as.matrix) %>% 
  map(`/`, 255) %>% 
  map(array, c(2, 3, 3)) %>% 
  iwalk(png::writePNG)
```

Or without the tidyverse:

```
z <- split(test_df, test_df$sample)
mapply(function(x, y) {
  png::writePNG(array(as.matrix(x[3:5]), c(2, 3, 3)) / 255, paste0(y, ".png"))
}, z, names(z))
```